# Understanding Choose Function

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Recently, I Come across one excel function called "Choose" which was mentioned as alternative for nested if function. I saw some examples in online like below comparing both nested if and choose function.

For the given criteria,

```
Result          Score
Poor            0 - 50
Satisfactory    51 - 100
Good            101 - 150
Excellent       over 151
```

The nested if condition will be like,

```
=IF(B2>=151, "Excellent", IF(B2>=101, "Good", IF(B2>=51, "Satisfactory", "Poor")))
```

and for the same situation, the choose function will be

```
=CHOOSE((B2>0) + (B2>=51) + (B2>=101) + (B2>=151), "Poor", "Satisfactory", "Good", "Excellent")
```

I understand that choose function works based on the index number or the position number from the given list of values (True conditions).

I am just thinking what if I add one more category like in the below table, i.e.,

```
Result          Score
Not Applicable   <0
Poor            0 - 50
Satisfactory    51 - 100
Good            101 - 150
Excellent       over 151
```

If I give the formula like this in choose,

```
=CHOOSE((B2<0)+(B2>0) + (B2>=51) + (B2>=101) + (B2>=151), "Not Applicable", "Poor", "Satisfactory", "Good", "Excellent")
```

However, I may end up with error for values like i.e., B2 = 21

This is just for learning purpose and it would be great if anyone help me to handle these situations when using choose option.

Comment: this may be off the topic, but I would use **LOOKUP**,  `approximate match` of **VLOOKUP**, or `less than` of **INDEX+MATCH** instead of **CHOOSE** just imagine you have 100 rows of the conditions.

Comment: Hi Terry, thanks for your options. As you mentioned, yes, we can use multiple other options. But, I just wanted to understand specifically on Choose function and how we can handle using this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

```
=IFERROR(CHOOSE(($D1>150) + ($D1>100) + ($D1>50) + ($D1>0), "Poor", "Satisfactory", "Good", "Excellent"),"Not Applicable")
```

[image: Solution]

You can use **IFERROR** to return `Not Applicable` for negative score. If the cell is blank it will be viewed as `0` and the formula will return `Poor`.

If you do not want to show `poor` for a blank cell, you can use a nested **CHOOSE** function as below to show a desired outcome such as blank `""` in the following formula:

```
=CHOOSE(IF(LEN($D1)=0,1,2),"",IFERROR(CHOOSE(($D1>150) + ($D1>100) + ($D1>50) + ($D1>=0), "Poor", "Satisfactory", "Good", "Excellent"),"Not Applicable"))
```

Comment: With respect, it's really not a good way. The LOOKUP function Terry mentioned in the comments was a *good* way; this is just unnecessarily convoluted. :)